# sqlite3 not locating the bindings.js foulder

Tags: javascript

ome/container/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:135
throw err;
^
Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
→ /home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/better_sqlite3.node
→ /home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Debug/better_sqlite3.node
→ /home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/better_sqlite3.node
→ /home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/out/Debug/better_sqlite3.node
→ /home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/Debug/better_sqlite3.node
→ /home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/out/Release/better_sqlite3.node
→ /home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/Release/better_sqlite3.node
→ /home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/default/better_sqlite3.node
→ /home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/compiled/16.20.2/linux/x64/better_sqlite3.node
→ /home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/addon-build/release/install-root/better_sqlite3.node
→ /home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/addon-build/debug/install-root/better_sqlite3.node
→ /home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/addon-build/default/install-root/better_sqlite3.node
→ /home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v93-linux-x64/better_sqlite3.node
at bindings (/home/container/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:126:9)
at new Database (/home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/database.js:48:64)
at new Enmap (/home/container/node_modules/enmap/src/index.js:152:18)
at Object. (/home/container/utils.js:1:7912)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1198:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18) {
tries: [
'/home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/better_sqlite3.node',
'/home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Debug/better_sqlite3.node',
'/home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/better_sqlite3.node',
'/home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/out/Debug/better_sqlite3.node',
'/home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/Debug/better_sqlite3.node',
'/home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/out/Release/better_sqlite3.node',
'/home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/Release/better_sqlite3.node',
'/home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/default/better_sqlite3.node',
'/home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/compiled/16.20.2/linux/x64/better_sqlite3.node',
'/home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/addon-build/release/install-root/better_sqlite3.node',
'/home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/addon-build/debug/install-root/better_sqlite3.node',
'/home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/addon-build/default/install-root/better_sqlite3.node',
'/home/container/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v93-linux-x64/better_sqlite3.node'
]
}

the bindings.js is on node modules with all stuffs

Comment: You literally just posted an error. Can y ou provide more informations and context.